# Angular combine multiple router events

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I just have an query I'm having an two router events snippet

```
    this.router.events.pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
      .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
        this.previousUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
        this.currentUrl = events[1].urlAfterRedirects;
});

this.router.events
.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart))
.subscribe((e: NavigationStart) => {
  const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
});
```

Though these are working fine individually,

In order to optimize, can I merge/combine this router events and use only one?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course we can. Why do we need to listen to the same event emitter twice?
You can do something like this:

```
    this.router.events.pipe(pairwise())
  .subscribe((events: any) => {
    if (events[0] instanceof NavigationStart) {
      const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    } else if (events[1] instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
      this.previousUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
      this.currentUrl = events[1].urlAfterRedirects;
    }
  });
```

Instead of filtering events up top, you listen to everything and apply your logic based on the event type.

Comment: probably you want to remove `.pipe(pairwise())`.

Comment: I just gave an example, keeping/ getting rid of it depends on the use case. :)

Comment: but `events` will be an array and therefore `if (events instanceof NavigationStart)` will always be false, right? or am I missing something?

Comment: @Zerotwelve, I see your point now. Updated accordingly!